# Launching a script in a new gnome-terminal

Tags: bash, gnome-terminal, sh

I am trying to make a script which is supposed to open a new gnome-terminal and issue a command (launch a jetty server).

If I try only : `gnome-terminal`, a new gnome-terminal is opened.

If I try : `gnome-terminal -e ls`, I get a warning message :

> Option “-e” is deprecated and might be removed in a later version of gnome-terminal.
>
> Use “-- ” to terminate the options and put the command line to execute after it.

Here, the new gnome-terminal is not always opened. If I try this command fast 10 times, maybe 2 terminal will open...

Same if I try with the recommended syntax : `gnome-terminal -- ls`.

What is the correct way to achieve this?

Comment: Hello, Arnaud Denoyelle, thank you for the updatete of my answer! Which is the Ubuntu version where `-e/-x` are depreciated?

Comment: @pa4080 I get this warning message on a 18.04 LTS